# pandas.errors.ParserError: ';' expected after '"'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am reading a semicolon delimited file using the following statement:

```
delimiter = ''
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
    delimiter = dialect.delimiter
if delimiter == '':
    delimiter = ','

data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=delimiter, quotechar='"', engine='python',encoding='ISO-8859-1', converters={i: str for i in range(0, 155)})
```

Everything typically works fine, but a came across a problem where double quotes are being passed within the double quote quotechar. Please see the sample below:

> "184 Pan Street";"Suite 300 Dock #12 "WD
> RMA"";"CALEXICO";"CA";"92231";"US"

I see examples where people have commas between quotechar, but never the problem I am facing. Please help! Thank you